# Can't read Base64 encoded image in Node.js which is sent from Python

Tags: python, node.js, opencv, base64, buffer

I'm trying to achieve communication between Node.js and Python. For this task, I'm using Node.js's python-shell NPM module to run a Python script and read the print output. I want to do some OpenCV image processing stuff on Python, send the image to Node.js and serve it on an application.

Here is the Node.js part:

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')

let options = {
  mode: 'text',
  pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
  args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
};

PythonShell.run('engine.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
/*   var fs = require("fs");

  fs.writeFile("arghhhh.jpeg", Buffer.from(results, "base64"), function(err) {}); */
  console.log(results.toString())
});
```

Here is the Python part:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2 as cv2
import base64

source = cv2.imread("60_3.tif", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# tried making it a PIL image but didn't change anything
# source = Image.fromarray(source)
print(base64.b64encode(source))
```

Everything looks good in theory, however, I tried to write the image on Node.js side and I can't open the image. Also checked sizes of the both strings and there was 3 character difference on Node.js side. 
Do I need to do something else in between to share a simple image between two languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import cv2 as cv2
import base64

source = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.png', source)
content = encoded_image.tobytes()
print(base64.b64encode(content).decode('ascii'))
```

This is how I figured it out. Encoding image with OpenCV's imencode method and converting it to bytes with .tobytes() is curial. Also, the image as bytes needs to be encoded and decoded as 'ascii' to be read on the NodeJS part.

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably running your script with `python` 2, but the library you're using is using `python3`, and your string will look something like `b'aGVsbG8='` instead of `aGVsbG8=`.

Try running from your shell

```
python3 engine.py
```

Comment: No, the project is in a virtualenv which is on Python 3.7.4. I can pass the base64 string just like your example it starts with `b'JDJMRkVTUU9R` however I still can't work with it on Node.js. Tried to write it to a file but still no image.

Comment: because when you want to use it in node you have to remove `b'` and `'` in the end. Are you doing that already?

Comment: yeah, the string has 'b'' at the beginning and ''' at the end, I tried to remove those and create a buffer from that to write the image but I still can't open the image file.

Answer (score 0):

**python code # cv.py**

```
import cv2 as cv2
import base64

source = cv2.imread('0.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.png', source)
content = encoded_image.tobytes()
print(base64.b64encode(content).decode('ascii'))
```

**nodejs code**

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const fs = require('fs');

const process = spawn('python', ['./cv.py']);

process.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log(data.toString()); 
  fs.writeFile("test.png", Buffer.from(data.toString(), "base64"), function(err) {});
});
```